# Background image overlapping inserted images

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with HTML & CSS and is trying to make a pretty simple "under contruction" page. I made the background black and text white. I placed the text where I wanted and are not trying to insert an image below the text. I got the image into the site, but somehow it is behind my background? Anyone who got a clue what to do?

Heres my CSS code:

```
    .fullscreenDiv {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
.center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
    margin-left: -190px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.trademark {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Century Gothic
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class='fullscreenDiv'>
    <div class="center">Our website is currently under construction.</div>
</div>

<div class='fullScreenDiv'>
    <div class="trademark">@GameAdviser - Copyright 2014</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Just a quick problem now, I made it worked placed my picture, and uploaded it to my FTP, now when I enter the website I can't see my picture, just a border with the "image not aviable" image or whatever it is. Seems strange since I had a picture before which worked fine.

Tried to change it from png to jpeg but didn't make a difference.

Comment: There's no image in your code

Comment: Why dont you use the body as the `fullscreenDiv` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use z-index like

```
z-index:199; // for the Element you want on top
z-index:-199; // for the Element you want at bottom
```

Comment: Hey Hey Hey bro Then ACCEPT my answer I am answering for reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index` property to `.center`  and change the class name  `fullscreenDiv` instead of `fullScreenDiv` case sensitive.

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/MBaem/)**

```
 .center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
}
```